# Best puzzles of 2018 Q4 (October - December)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the fourth quarter ( October / November / December ) 2018?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - Algorithmically selected "best of":
>
>   - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2018 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2018&month=10#query-results)
>   - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2018 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2018&month=10#query-results)
> - Best by votes/views:
>
>   - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2018 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2018/10/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2018 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2018/10/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2018 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2018/10/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>

  - <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
  - <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
  - <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

## [The Two-Trench Truce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75268/the-two-trench-truce) by [Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49474/level-51)

In the words of ManyPinkHats who solved it:

> That is a **very** impressive amount of content to fit in such a tiny cryptic.

This is one of those puzzles that, even upon seeing the solution, I look at and still wonder how the creator actually went about crafting it. Multiple layers of moving parts all crammed into a tiny package make for an impressive effort from a purely technical perspective. However, add to that a thematic consistency and conclusion that makes you smile and you've got a truly great puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

## [lolcatz can haz ur infinit cheeseboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74037/36023) by [deep thought](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18776/deep-thought)

User [deep thought](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18776/deep-thought) took a chess board, expanded it into infinity, and added one (1) chess piece with extraordinarily clever (if somewhat complicated) movement rules.

The result? A chess problem that the entire humankind (well, at least, all the mathematicians) would applaud if ever solved.

Answer (score 2):

## [Which movie will we watch?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75142/which-movie-will-we-watch) by [formica](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52581/formica)

I spent a ton of time on (and really enjoyed) this puzzle.

I think it was quite simple and elegant in its construction, but still managed to stump the majority of the community for a significant amount of time, even with the 5.5 clues provided by the OP